# Find upper bound on number of grandparents

Tags: combinatorics

There is a group of $20$ children and a group of $n$ grandparents to these children. Each of these grandparents is either father's father or mother's father to at least one of these children. Now, following constraints are given:

1. Each pair of children has at least one grandparent in common who is also present in this group of grandparents.
2. Every grandparent has at least two grandchildren in this group of children.

Find upper bound on $n$, the number of grandparents present in the group such that above constraints can be satisfied.

Comment: I have a solution with $n=11$ grandfathers. What is your largest value so far?

Comment: Add your solution to the question!

Answer (score 1):

"is either father's father or mother's father to at least one of these children" -> this means we are talking only about grandfathers.

See [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23221/72672).

In short each child can have max 2 grandfathers and the upper bound for *n* is 3 in order for the first constraint to be satisfied.